# On nixos, how to configure the firewall to restrict access to only certain domains?

Tags: firewall, nixos

I would like to configure my nixos machine to only connect to certain domains.

In the [firewall section](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-firewall) of the nixos manual, I see how to specify `networking.firewall.enable` to enable the firewall.

However I do not see any way to configure it to restrict access to only certain domains.
I looked through all `networking.firewall` options in the manual (listed [here](https://search.nixos.org/options?channel=22.11&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=networking.firewall)), and do not see there any options that do that.

How do I configure the nixos firewall to only permit access to certain whitelisted domains?

Comment: Is is the case that NixOS uses `nftables` to manage firewall rules? If so, here's a [good reference](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Simple_rule_management).

Comment: Normal firewalling doesn't deal with domain names.  (regardless of your operating system)  People either block on their DNS server or use more complex workarounds like https://git.zx2c4.com/ipset-dns/about/

Comment: @VladimírČunát what's the best way to do this? Should I be looking into dnsmasq instead, using it to run a local DNS server which only forwards the specified hostnames to DNS while blocking all others?